# Struts2 IllegalStateException on first visit

Tags: session, struts2, browser-cache, illegalstateexception

I have a protected page that is supposed to redirect to the login screen when not logged in.  The issue is that when i try to view that page, instead of redirecting to login it crashes with a IllegalStateException error.  The kicker is that if I manually visit the login page it loads, then I try to visit the protect page again and it will redirect as expected.  It must be some sort of session caching issue because the problem will never happen again unless i restart the browser.  After a browser restart the issue will continue until I manually visit the login page again.  And of course the error reporting is super vague to what the issue actually is

```
Aug 20, 2013 4:36:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:407)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:852)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:534)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

My Interceptor that I use to validate if they are logged in and redirect when neccessary.  the very first `return BaseAction.Login` hits like its supposed to, and when I enable logging the struts2 loggers indicate a redirect to viewLogin is going to happen, but it doesn't.  I just crashes instead:

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    BaseAction action = (BaseAction)invocation.getAction();
LoginManager loginManager = (LoginManager)action.getSession().get("loginManager");
Boolean loggedIn = false;

    final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext(); 
    ActionMapping mapping = (ActionMapping)context.get(ServletActionContext.ACTION_MAPPING);


        if(loginManager == null && action.isLoginRequired()) {
            //user is not logged in and login required, redirect them to login module
            return BaseAction.LOGIN;
        } else if(loginManager != null && action.isLoginRequired()) {
            //logged in, make sure they are accessing a valid resource
            String loginKey = action.getSessionLoginVarable(mapping);
            if(loginManager.getLoginPaths().containsKey(loginKey)) {
                return invocation.invoke();
            } else {
                //return to login which will redirect them to appropriate path
                return BaseAction.LOGIN;
            }
        } else {
            //public access to continue with action
            return invocation.invoke();
        }
}
```

Struts-config file

```
<package name="student" namespace="/student" extends="struts-default-custom">
    <default-action-ref name="viewLogin" />
    <global-results>
        <result name="login" type="redirectAction">viewLogin</result>
    </global-results>

    <action name="*Login" method="{1}" class="controller.shared.StudentLogin">
        <interceptor-ref name="noLoginStack"/>

        <result type="redirectAction">viewSearchAdvisors</result>
        <result name="input">/student/student-login.jsp</result>
        <result name="error" type="redirectAction">viewLogin</result>
    </action>
```

So just to summaraize.  First visit to this protected page on browser startup it crashes instead of redirect to login.  I manually visit login page, then try to visit protected page no crash and it redirects back to login like its supposed to.  It will continue to work fine until i restart the browser.

any ideas??

Comment: Are you sure that is the _only_ stack trace? The one you posted indicates your code isn't even being invoked.

Comment: Yes that is the only stacktrace that appears in my IDE console as well as on the Tomcat 500 error page.  I have traced it though the debugger and my code is being run.  This exception appears AFTER going through my Intercepter and `return BaseAction.LOGIN`

Comment: Check catalina.out to see if there is anything else. That stack trace doesn't tell us what the problem is at all. Also, what puts LoginManager in session and why is that in a session?

Comment: I will check the catalina.out.  As for the LoginManager, that is set upon a successful login.  I reference it in this interceptor to determine if the user has successfully logged in or not, thus will redirect to login if it doesn't exist or the proper parameters are not set.  It contains various attributes specific to that user.

Comment: So naturally this is the only one of the only exceptions that is not logged in catalina.out.  It has all sorts of other exceptions from the past, but this one in particular i guess is beyond the scope of that log file...

Comment: issue is resolved, thanks @StevenBenitez for your assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is resolved.  I have absolutely no idea why, but when I changed my struts xml files to use this DTD file

http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd

instead of

http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd

the issue went away.  I was grasping at straws checking every configuration file against config files of other apps i have that use the same process without issue and saw this.  I decided what the hell and made the change...and it works.